# Java: How to get an objects listeners to work in a different class?

Tags: java, class, actionlistener

So I'm trying to get the DriverPC class to know when a button is being pressed in the Frame Object so it can use the DoThis() method, and am unsure of how to go about this situation.

DriverPC class:

```
public class DriverPC {
    private static void DoThis(){
        //Send information through already set up datastream when button in Frame clicked
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
    //set up bluetooth datastream
    communications();

    //create gui
    new Frame(200,200,200,200);
    }
}
```

Frame class:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    JButton butt = new JButton("Button");   

    Frame(int a,int b,int c, int d){
        super("My Simple Frame");
        setBounds(a,b,c,d);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container con = this.getContentPane();
        butt.addActionListener(this);
        con.add(pane);
        pane.add(butt);
        setVisible(true);       
    }   

    public void  actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source == butt){
        }
    }
}
```

Just wondering if it is possible and if not how should I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the line

```
butt.addActionListener(this);
```

in your `Frame` constructor, you are delegating the button pressed event to the method `Frame.actionPerformed`.

As your `DoThis` method is declared as static you can simply call it in that method:

```
public void  actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if (source == butt) {
        DriverPC.DoThis();
    }
}
```

To make this work, the `DoThis` method must also be public (or at least package private, I guess):

```
public static void DoThis() {
    System.out.println("Awesome");
}
```

Now the output will be printed in the console, whenever you press your button.

By the way: Please conform to the Java Code Conventions, and start method names with lower case letters:

```
public static void doThis() { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make the DoThis() method **public**.

```
public static void DoThis(){
    System.out.println("Awesome");
}
```

Then just call the method in your actionPerformed method:

```
public void  actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if (source == butt){
        DriverPC.DoThis();
    }
}
```

This works for me! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add another `ActionListener` to the button like this:

**DriverPC**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class DriverPC implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        final Frame frame = new Frame(200, 200, 200, 200);

        frame.addActionListenerToButton(new DriverPC());
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private static void DoThis() {
        System.out.println("Awesome");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        DoThis();
    }

}
```

**Frame**

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6585300413498042106L;

    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    JButton butt = new JButton("Button");

    Frame(final int a, final int b, final int c, final int d) {
        super("My Simple Frame");

        setBounds(a, b, c, d);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final Container con = this.getContentPane();

        butt.addActionListener(this);
        con.add(pane);
        pane.add(butt);
    }

    public void addActionListenerToButton(final ActionListener listener) {
        butt.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event) {
        // ...
    }

}
```